# Change rails time formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some times that I am showing in my view

```
<td><%= something.foo_time %></td>
<td><%= something.bar_time %></td>
```

Right now they display as

```
2000-01-01 05:24:00 UTC
2000-01-01 15:24:00 UTC
```

But since I am not collecting the date, I want to just show the time, but in AM/PM style without the year and time zone.

I have tried using the strf formating http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime but it does not work

```
<td><%= something.foo_time("%I:%M%p") %></td>
```

I also tried

```
<td><%= something.foo_time "%H:%M:" %></td>
```

And It did not work either.

How can I go from

```
2000-01-01 15:24:00 UTC
```

To

```
3:24 PM
```

Answer (score 1):

you can always create a helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
   def display_date(input_date)
    if !input_date
      return ''
    end

    return input_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
  end

end
```

and then call in your view like `<%= display_date time_var %>`
my example doesn't format the date to AM/PM style, but you can easily find how to do this on the documentation, like the link you've posted: `t.strftime("at %I:%M%p")            #=> "at 08:37AM"`

my method could be changed to `return input_date.strftime("%I:%M%p")` according to the link

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to do this:

```
something.foo_time.strftime("%I:%M%p")
```

However, I'd look into Rails' DATE_FORMATS at the following URL and either use a default if it exists, or create your own by adding it via an initializer.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html

Then you can do this:

```
something.foo_time.to_s(:time)
```